# Access to file on network on Mac

Tags: asp.net, .net, macos

There is a server configuration file that is only accessible by connecting to a VPN. As we are using .Net Core, the server configuration file location is in `appsettings.json`. In my limited experience with Mac, I'm unsure how to set it up. We access the file in Windows - "`\\network-directory\fileName`" and only when connected to a VPN. Connecting through the finder network location (smb://x.x.x.x/development) worked, but not when running the project **(System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException)**.

### appsettings.json

```
{
  ServerConfigurationFiles: "\\\\network-directory\\fileName"
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems like an odd use case. If you're cloud hosted, I'd recommend using something like [Azure App Configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-app-configuration/overview) or [AWS AppConfig](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appconfig/latest/userguide/what-is-appconfig.html). These configurations-as-a-service are manageable, role-based, secure, and platform agnostic.

**That said**, if you have to do this, you have a few options on a Mac, but first and foremost you need to mount the network share.

In MacOS using **Finder**:

1. In the Finder menu, select "Go" then "Connect to Server".
2. Enter the address of the server. It might look something like this: `smb://ServerName/ShareName`
3. If prompted for a username and password. Enter the credentials you use to access the network resource.
4. Once connected, the network share should appear in the Finder, and you can navigate its folders as you would with any local directory.

In MacOS using the **bash shell** (SMB):

You can use the `mount` command along with `mount_smbfs`.

1. Create a mount point: (`mkdir /path/to/local/mountpoint`)
2. Mount the network share: (`mount_smbfs //[user[:password]@]server/share /path/to/local/mountpoint`)

Once mounted, you can navigate and manage files on the network share as if it's a local directory

After the network share is mounted, files on that share will have paths that reference the mounted location. For example, if you mounted a share to `/Volumes/shared-folder`, and you're trying to access a file named document.txt in a folder named Docs, the path would be `/Volumes/shared-folder/Docs/document.txt`.

There are additional ways to access it through a Terminal (bash shell):

AFP (Apple Filing Protocol)
`afp://myusername@myserver.com/shared-folder/Docs/document.txt`

SMB (Server Message Block)
`smb://myusername@myserver.com/shared-folder/Docs/document.txt`

NFS (Network File Share)
`nfs://myserver.com:/shared-folder/Docs/document.txt`

Comment: Matt, thanks for your suggestions. I will try and see if the workarounds work. Anyway, we are planning on moving the shared file to the cloud. That looks like the best solution.